# php preg_replace trailing minus sign

Tags: php, preg-replace

I try to remove a trialing minus sign of a string.

I've got the following code:

```
$name = preg_replace("/\-$/ismU", "", trim($name));
```

I also tried:

```
$name = preg_replace("/\\\-$/ismU", "", trim($name));
```

and:

```
$name = preg_replace("/-$/ismU", "", trim($name));
```

But that does not seem to work, any ideas what I do wrong? That's should be simple issue but somehow I can't get it to work.

Comment: [`$name = preg_replace("/-$/ismU", "", trim($name));`](http://codepad.org/Z01KJs3Y) should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use rtrim to get any trailing minus signs

```
 $name = rtrim(trim($name), "-");
```

for multiline you can do preg_replace but make sure to account for the trailing spaces

```
 $name = preg_replace('/- *$/ismU', "", trim($name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = preg_replace("/\\-$/ismU", "", trim($name)); // double quotes, escape \
```

or

```
$name = preg_replace('/\-$/ismU', "", trim($name)); // double quotes, escape \ (works)
$name = preg_replace('/\\-$/ismU', "", trim($name)); // double quotes, escape \ (proper)
```